# reading optional attributes from optional setting in javascript

Tags: javascript, arguments, option-type

What is the most efficient way of reading optional attributes in an optional setting argument. I'm using something like:

```
f = func(var1, optionalsettings) {
    var2 = (optionalsettings === undefined ? 0 
         : (optionalsettings['var2'] == null ? 0 : optionalsettings['var2']));
};
```

But I've the feeling it can be done more efficiently, either in javascript or in jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do:

```
var var2 = (optionalsettings && optionalsettings['var2']) || 0;
```

First you check is `optionalsettings` exists. If it does, you try to return `optionalsettings['var2']`. If that fails, you fall back on the default value.

Comment: Note that it would work without parentheses, as `&&` takes precedence to `||`, but it is slightly more readable that way.

Answer (score 0):

also possible jquery's extend:

```
function myTest(arg1, arg2, optionalsettings) {
   var settings = $.extend( {
     opt1 : val1
     , opt2 : val2}, optionalsettings || {})
...
```